# Arrow key events with jQuery not working in anything other than Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have created a portfolio site and whilst browsing the images, I want users to be able to navigate using the arrow keys. I have the following code which works fine in Firefox but not Chrome, Safari or IE.

```
$(document).keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 39) { 
      evt.preventDefault(); 
      $.scrollTo('+=564px', 800, { axis:'x' }); 
    } else if (evt.keyCode == 37) { 
      evt.preventDefault();
      $.scrollTo('-=564px', 800, { axis:'x' });
    }
  });
```

I have the `scrollTo` plugin installed and working as well as a valid jQuery file so it's not an issue with these. Can anyine tell me why this might not function in other browsers?

Live example [here](http://nataliefeather.com/projects/drawings/).

Help always appreciated!

Comment: Do you get the expected behavior in FF3 or 4? In FF3, it's definitely wonky.

Comment: I'm using FF 3.6 and it works fine to me. It has now been updated with the code suggested by @Neurofluxation below, see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(evt) {

});
```

instead of

```
$(document).keypress(function(evt) {

});
```

This is because IE handles KeyPress differently to FireFox.

**EDIT** as you were so nice about getting a decent answer:

I would also change your statement to a `switch`:

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(evt) {
        switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case 65:
                    alert("you pressed key 65");
                    break;
                }
});
```

Comment: What a hero! Thanks for this, has made my day!

Comment: +1, `keydown` is definitely the correct event. You could use `$(document).keydown(function(evt) {});` instead of `bind()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make this cross-browser, you should also be aware the keyCodes may not be the same across browsers. jQuery offers the property `event.which`, which is supposed to normalize the differences between browers.

http://api.jquery.com/event.which

**From the docs:**

> `event.which` normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input.

Comment: +1 You were a little quicker. :o) Using `event.which` should properly solve the issue if OP does want the `keypress` event (which is not the same as `keydown`). Either way, `event.which` is the recommended property to use.

Comment: @Andrea, @patrick: `keypress` is the wrong event for handling non-printable keys such as arrow keys, which is what the OP was after.

Comment: I agree. This is why I wrote "You should **also** be aware..." :-)

Comment: @Andrea: The problem is not detecting which key was pressed, it's whether the event is fired at all. In some browsers, `keypress` is not fired for arrow keypresses. `keydown` always fires.